# Is it possible to detect a battery type and requirements(voltage,current etc) using an MCU based circuit?

Tags: microcontroller, batteries

I am trying to build a generic circuit to detect different types of batteries (lithium ,lead acid etc) based on automatic and quick tests for a potential product.

Is this  possible using an mcu and and electronic circuit?

Comment: Highly unlikely.

Comment: Google multi-chemistry battery charger.

Comment: As a practical matter, this is not really feasible. Especially the determination of battery capacity and optimum charging current. So I wouldn't invest any time on this, unless you find it to be a fun diversion.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible if the battery is not in a defect or deep discharged state. Based on the initial voltage and a defined discharge you can determine the battery type. The discharge curve looks very different for different chemistries.
I have seen lately on Ebay a device that measures the battery capacity. If I am not wrong it also determines the battery chemistry. So it should be not too hard to figure it out.